# Cyclic executive with thread?

Tags: c, multithreading, embedded, system

I am working on a project with a simple embedded system used in a router.

In the project, I have to run a set of tasks in cyclic executive.

The requirement is that 'each task is represented by a thread.'

Without a thread this is implemented as follows.

Table of pointers to tasks(functions)

```
void (*ttable[SLOTX][CYCLEX])() = {
    {one, one, two, two},
    {three, three, three, burn},
    {one, one, two, two},
    {three, three, three, burn},
    { two, two, one, one},
    {two, two, burn, burn}
};
```

where the functions are some simple print function with sleep

```
void one() {
  printf("Task 1 running\n");
  sleep(1);
}
```

and iterate the task table in a `for` loop and call each.

Now, what I am wondering is how using threads for each task in cyclic executive like this is useful, and if so, specifically in what way should I use threads.

---

The specification states 'Each function can create a thread and pass another function into the create function to show which task is executing.'

Comment: Threads are managed by an OS. Which OS are you using? How are the threads created and scheduled? What is the `create()` function?

Comment: @UncleO - the power is *writing* their own Operating System, albeit a primitive one.  They are actually implementing the scheduler which makes threads work.

Comment: @ChrisStratton This is why I ask the question. I suspect it is a homebrew OS as well, but was not presumptuous in my comment. The OS specification defines what "tasks" and "threads" are. I am asking OP to add those details to his question so that it can be answered. If you have those details, please share them.